# Why does Microsoft Graph Delta Query not return ModifiedBy property?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api

My usecase requires to fetch **ModifiedBy** attribute along with other metadata for a list of file system objects from my SharePoint drive.
The problem is that **it's missing from the default response**, and even if I add it under **$select** property, it doesn't give me ModifiedBy attribute.
**Any idea why?** CreatedBy is present though.

Comment: If you're talking about [lastmodifiedby property then its omitted when you make delta query - it's by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: The link says even ctag is missing but I see it in the response. Also I am making the delta query for a SharePoint drive and not OneDrive.